# Error con paquete arch

Tags: python, jupyter, cython, google-colab

tengo el siguiente error  que obtengo al correr from arch import arch_model

**AttributeError: type object 'arch.univariate.recursions.array' has no attribute '__reduce_cython__'**

Lo he corrido en mi laptop (windows) en jupyter notebook y no ha funcionado , sin embargo en el google colab (linux) si ha corrido tranquilamente. saben a que se debe

Comment: ¿Tienes cython instalado?

Comment: hola, ya lo logre solucionar actualizando el conda (conda update conda) e instalando como administrador los paquetes. igualmente gracias